# Source of the X-Men's mutations?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a set limit on mutant abilities, where they're deemed too unrealistic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/is-there-a-set-limit-on-mutant-abilities-where-theyre-deemed-too-unrealistic)

In X-Men: First Class (2011) Prof X hypothesizes that the source of the spike in human mutation is the advent of the atomic age.

Is this same explanation given in the comic book continuity?

Comment: The answer I got [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/is-there-a-set-limit-on-mutant-abilities-where-theyre-deemed-too-unrealistic) is related, but not really a duplicate.

Comment: This was answered explaining the source of mutations in the Marvel Universe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17418/2765. This effectively answers the question.

Comment: While I enjoyed the movie, X-Men First Class was so far from canon that I don't think any information from that movie is credible.

Comment: @Izkata - Indeed that's it. Should the question be closed as duplicate? It's a different question.

Comment: @SystemDown I'm not completely sure.  The question I'm asking there is rather different, even though the answer fully qualifies for this one..

Comment: We want answers and questions to grow the content on the site, so when another answer fully addresses a newly-asked question, the new question is closed as a duplicate.  Even when the two questions aren't exact matches.